# App crash in image capturing

Tags: ios6, xcode5, image-capture

I am capturing images in application and my app getting Received memory warning and app getting crash
       Below is code am using ... please help.
this application is like pick images from gallery and add animation to them . while animation is running will capture images and make them video.

I am getting memory warning when capturing images while animation..

```
-(void)captureImage:(NSTimer*) t {
NSLog(@"captureImage");


// Create a graphics context with the target size
// On iOS 4 and later, use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to take the scale into  consideration
// On iOS prior to 4, fall back to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext
CGSize imageSize = CGSizeZero;

UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = 
[UIApplication    sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {
    imageSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;
    NSLog(@"imageSize:%@  ",NSStringFromCGSize(imageSize));
} else {
    imageSize = 
 CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, 
 [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);
//CGSizeMake(animatedImgView.frame.size.width, animatedImgView.frame.size.height);//
}

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, NO, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
for (UIWindow *window in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {


    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, window.center.x, window.center.y);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, window.transform);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context,
  -window.bounds.size.width * window.layer.anchorPoint.x, 
 -window.bounds.size.height * window.layer.anchorPoint.y);
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI_2);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -imageSize.width);
    } else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        CGContextRotateCTM(context, -M_PI_2);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -imageSize.height, 0);
    } else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        CGContextRotateCTM(context, M_PI);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -imageSize.width, -imageSize.height);
    }
    if 
([window
respondsToSelector:@selector(drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:)])     {
         [window drawViewHierarchyInRect:window.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
        //[animatedImgView drawViewHierarchyInRect:window.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];
    } else {

        //[window.layer.presentationLayer renderInContext:context];
    }
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    }


 //   @autoreleasepool {
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    [savedImages addObject:image];
    image = nil;
 //  }

  }
```

Help is appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I think setting the image to nil is not enough. See:
[The following graphical code tagged as Leak by iOS ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853845/the-following-graphical-code-tagged-as-leak-by-ios-arc)

Another cause for the exception can be that you have to many images in the memory. Where are they stored? Filesystem? Database? Memory?